# Covert one column of a dataframe to a spacy doc

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

How do I turn one column of a DataFrame into a SPACY doc so I can analyze Part of Speech and etc.?

I tried :

```
df['new_col'] = df['Old_col'].apply(lambda x: nlp(x))
```

How do I get the POC count of the `new_col`?
I tried

```
pos_count = df['new_col'].count_by(spacy.attrs.POS)
```

but the error I am getting is:

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'count_by'

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your first statement

```
df['new_col'] = df['Old_col'].apply(lambda x: nlp(x))
```

should work (at least for every use I've had for it.

It looks like what you're trying to do in the second is count the parts of speech for all the tokens in the doc?

If so something like this should work:

```
def pos_count(spacy_doc):
    num_pos = [t.pos_ for t in doc if t.pos_ != None]
    return len(num_pos)

df_msg['new_col'].apply(lambda c: pos_count(spacy_doc = c))
```

It really isn't clear from your second snippt what you **want**.